# How get javaclass from java type array in Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

For pojo classes:

```
//java
MyClass.getClass();
//kotlin
MyClass::class.java
```

But how getClass from array?

```
//java
MyClass[].class;
//kotlin
???
```

`MyClass[]::class.java` - does not work :(

Comment: Java syntax would actually be `.class`, not `.getClass()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's simple:

```
Array<String>::class.java
// on objects 
args.javaClass
```

Arrays in Kotlin don't look as `MyClass[]`, this is Java. Always use `Array` class with generic types. For primitives there are specialized versions like `IntArray`.

Comment: This works but won't if List is used instead of Array.